# Entity framework core recursive navigated table query takes long time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

I have an organization entity/table which one organization could be other one's parent (recursive) in my application. I have made a organization tree view, as below (just sample), which all works fine. I have approx 3000 organization entry.

[image]

However, the query which ef core creates takes some unignorable time, approx **6000ms** *(checked with SE miniprofiler and sql event profiler both)*,

Here organization entity, its context configuration and recursive(child entities included) get method, respectively.

```
public class OrganizationEntity : BaseEntity
{
    public int TkId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string TextEn { get; set; }
    public int? TkTopId { get; set; }
    public int LevelCode { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public Guid? ParentOrganizationId { get; set; }
    public virtual OrganizationEntity ParentOrganization { get; set; }

    public Guid? ManagerId { get; set; }
    public virtual EmployeeEntity Manager { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OrganizationEntity> ChildOrganizations { get; set; }
}

private void ConfigureOrganization(EntityTypeBuilder<OrganizationEntity> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Organization");
    builder.HasMany(o => o.ChildOrganizations).WithOne(o => o.ParentOrganization).HasForeignKey(o => o.ParentOrganizationId);
}


public List<OrganizationEntity> GetAll()
{
    var organizations = _organizationRepository.Get(includeProperties: "ChildOrganizations").ToList();
    var parentOrganizations = organizations.Where(x => x.ParentOrganization == null).ToList();

    return parentOrganizations;
}
```

The line

> `_organizationRepository.Get(includeProperties:"ChildOrganizations").ToList();`

produce the following sql query.

**Original Query**

```
SELECT [e].[Id], [e].[City], [e].[CountryCode], [e].[CreatedBy], [e].[CreatedOn], [e].[IsDeleted], [e].[LevelCode], [e].[ManagerId], [e].[ModifiedBy], [e].[ModifiedOn], [e].[OrderId], [e].[ParentOrganizationId], [e].[Text], [e].[TextEn], [e].[TkId], [e].[TkTopId]
FROM [Organization] AS [e]
WHERE [e].[IsDeleted] = 0
ORDER BY [e].[Id]
```

**Include Query**

```
SELECT [e0].[Id], [e0].[City], [e0].[CountryCode], [e0].[CreatedBy], [e0].[CreatedOn], [e0].[IsDeleted], [e0].[LevelCode], [e0].[ManagerId], [e0].[ModifiedBy], [e0].[ModifiedOn], [e0].[OrderId], [e0].[ParentOrganizationId], [e0].[Text], [e0].[TextEn], [e0].[TkId], [e0].[TkTopId]
FROM [Organization] AS [e0]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [e1].[Id]
    FROM [Organization] AS [e1]
    WHERE [e1].[IsDeleted] = 0
) AS [t] ON [e0].[ParentOrganizationId] = [t].[Id]
WHERE [e0].[IsDeleted] = 0
ORDER BY [t].[Id]
```

Well, when I run these queries on sql server management studio, both together takes only approx 350ms. What could be the reason of this delay?

**Edit, Repository Code**

```
public IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null, string includeProperties = null, bool asNoTracking = false, int? skip = null, int? take = null)
           => GetQueryable(filter, orderBy, includeProperties, asNoTracking, skip, take);

protected virtual IQueryable<T> GetQueryable(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter = null, Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
                                                    string includeProperties = null,
                                                    bool asNoTracking = false,
                                                    int? skip = null,
                                                    int? take = null)
{
    includeProperties = includeProperties ?? string.Empty;
    IQueryable<T> query = _dbContext.Set<T>();

    if (filter != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(filter);
    }

    foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
        (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        query = query.Include(includeProperty);
    }

    if (orderBy != null)
    {
        query = orderBy(query);
    }

    if (skip.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Skip(skip.Value);
    }

    if (take.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Take(take.Value);
    }

    if (asNoTracking)
    {
        query = query.AsNoTracking();
    }

    return query;
}
```

Comment: EF can build an entire hierarchy for a self-referential relationship with a single inner join, thanks to object-fixup. As you've noticed, the query is very minimal and relatively quick. EF, too, is relatively quick, although depending on how many organizations are being loaded in, it could take a while to build the object graph. A few thousand? No issue. A few million? You might have some performance problems. Frankly, I'm apt to blame your repo, since I've frankly never seen one that didn't bork something or another with how EF works.

Comment: hey @ChrisPratt this is weird because I am using the repoistory bits of [yours'](https://cpratt.co/generic-entity-base-class) :) - with just a little modification. I updated the question with the repo code.

Comment: while playing just found out that, enabling `asNoTracking()` did the trick and query duration is shortened. However, I don't understand why `asNoTracking()`s the latency (_which is something performance tuning of ef core's plays with memory_), seems like a problem with sql (at least on mini profiler and sql event profiler)

Comment: Well, if you've got a ton of results coming back, `AsNoTracking()` will help, as it's not trying to do change tracking on all that, which is a lot of compute. Latency can be an issue with large result sets as well, as it takes time to build the result set and time to transfer it. I'm not sure how many things you're pulling in, but it might be beneficial to do something like paging or at least batching of the results.

Comment: Paging is not needed on a treeview and as I mentioned in the post, I am pullling 3000 records from db as well, not too much. I guess tracking process on self-referential objects has something time consuming from the perspective of building result set on sql side. Maybe... Thanks for your thoughts @ChrisPratt

Answer (score 0):

Enabling `AsNoTracking()` on query made the query's execution duration to normal level(as same as in sql server).

> `_organizationRepository.Get(includeProperties:"ChildOrganizations", asNoTracking: true).ToList();`